# what happened to python dict's key default sort

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

for i want to decode a dict to json,but i found the output order is not i desired,then i do a test like this:

```
a = {'a':'1st','ab':'2nd'}
print(a)
a = {'b':'1st','bc':'2nd'}
print(a)
a = {'c':'1st','cd':'2nd'}
print(a)
a = {'d':'1st','de':'2nd'}
print(a)
a = {'e':'1st','ef':'2nd'}
print(a)
a = {'f':'1st','fg':'2nd'}
print(a)
```

out put is

```
{'a': '1st', 'ab': '2nd'}
{'b': '1st', 'bc': '2nd'}
{'c': '1st', 'cd': '2nd'}
{'de': '2nd', 'd': '1st'}
{'ef': '2nd', 'e': '1st'}
{'fg': '2nd', 'f': '1st'}
```

because d is 100 in ascii?

how to explain it?can i change the iter order?

Comment: sorry i didn't know how to accept until i found the mark below the number:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries aren't sorted in Python. If you want sorted dictionaries, use `OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> a = OrderedDict((('f','1st'),('fg','2nd')))
>>> a
OrderedDict([('f', '1st'), ('fg', '2nd')])
```

In order to construct an `OrderedDict`, however, you need to use an object that preserves its sort order, like a `list` or a `tuple`.

Answer (score 1):

`dict` items have no order. Whatever order arises is an implementation detail -- you can't count on it.

If you need the items to be ordered, use a [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) (introduced in Python 2.7).

```
In [1]: import collections
In [9]: a = collections.OrderedDict([('d', '1st'), ('de', '2nd')])

In [10]: a
Out[10]: OrderedDict([('d', '1st'), ('de', '2nd')])
```